# How to plot multiple lines in R

Tags: r, plot

I have a data that looks like this:

```
#d  TRUE    FALSE   Cutoff
4   28198   0   0.1
4   28198   0   0.2
4   28198   0   0.3
4   28198   13  0.4
4   28251   611 0.5
4   28251   611 0.6
4   28251   611 0.7
4   28251   611 0.8
4   28251   611 0.9
4   28251   611 1
6   19630   0   0
6   19630   0   0.1
6   19630   0   0.2
6   19630   0   0.3
6   19630   0   0.4
6   19636   56  0.5
6   19636   56  0.6
6   19636   56  0.7
6   19636   56  0.8
6   19636   56  0.9
6   19636   56  1
```

So I want to plot them based on True (Y-axis) and False (X-axis).

This is the way I want it to appear roughly.
[image: This is the way I want it to appear roughly]

What's the right way to do it?
My code below fails

```
dat<-read.table("mydat.txt", header=F);
dis     <- c(4,6);
linecols <-c("red","blue");
plot(dat$V2 ~ dat$V3, data = dat,  xlim = c(0,611),ylim =c(0,28251), type="l")

for (i in 1:length(dis)){
datax <- subset(dat, dat$V1==dis[i], select = c(dat$V2,dat$V3))
lines(datax,lty=1,type="l",col=linecols[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since your data is already in long format and I like ggplot graphics anyway, I'd suggest that path. After reading your data in (note that `TRUE` and `FALSE` are not valid names, so R appended a `.` to the column names), the following should work:

```
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(FALSE., TRUE., colour = as.factor(d), group = as.factor(d))) + 
  geom_line()
```

The [ggplot2](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/) website is full of good tips. Also note [this search query on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[r]+add+multiple+lines+plot) for lots of other good tips on related topics.

[image]

And for the record, here's how I'd approach your problem modifying your original code:

```
colnames(dat)[2:3] <- c("T", "F")

dis <- unique(dat$d)

plot(NA, xlim = c(0, max(dat$F)), ylim = c(0, max(dat$T)))
for (i in seq_along(dis)){
  subdat <- subset(dat, d == dis[i])
  with(subdat, lines(F,T, col = linecols[i]))
}
legend("bottomright", legend=dis, fill=linecols)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks. After reading data. It gave me this error: Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'FALSE.' not found.

Comment: @neversaint - My guess is that R is having problems since TRUE and FALSE are reserved words in R. Change your column names to something like T and F and all should be fine. I shouldn't have even tried to put the example together with those names...it will just lead to trouble for your. `colnames()` is the function you're after.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a base R method, assuming your data is called `dat` in this example:

```
plot(1:max(dat$false), xlim = c(0,611),ylim =c(19000,28251), type="n")

apply(
rbind(unique(dat$d),1:2),
#the 1:2 here are your chosen colours
2,
function(x) lines(dat$false[dat$d==x[1]],dat$true[dat$d==x[1]],col=x[2])
)
```

Result:

[image]

edit - while using lowercase true/false for variable names is accepted, it probably still isn't the greatest coding practice.